# Setting up Auth0 in Express API: How do i export this constant in order to use it in routes files?

Tags: node.js, express, auth0

Im setting up Auth0 for an API and i managed to make it work following the docs, but i want to control which endpoints are protected instead of using `app.use(jwtCheck)`. So i want to export the jwtCheck constant marked in red here:

[image]

To use it here (ignore the Auth.isStorage, its a custom auth im getting rid of):

[image]

But it just wont work. I tried export, export default, module.exports, but its always undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: My bad. I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks.

Comment: Why wait till next time? [Edit] your question to fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a circular dependency

> `index.js` <- `Routes` <- `Routes/Item.js` <- `index.js`

Simply move the `jwtCheck` to its own module (file).

For example

```js
// middleware/auth.js

import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";

export const jwtCheck = auth({
  audience: "http://localhost:3000", // suggest you use env vars
  issuerBaseURL: "https://...",
  tokenSigningAlg: "RS256",
});
```

Then you can import it wherever required

```js
// Routes/Item.js

import { jwtCheck } from "../middleware/auth";
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense and i even had something like that with the custom auth. Thanks a lot!